# Pyhon3.6.2 и pystardict (0.6 или 0.7) совместимы? Кто исправлял pystardict .py?

Tags: python-3.x

```
  self.idx = _StarDictIdx(dict_prefix=filename_prefix, container=self)
File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pystardict.py", line 158, in __init__
  matched_records = re.findall(record_pattern, self._file)
File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 221, in findall
  return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

***Repl Closed***

+ 'record_pattern=record_pattern.encode()' - сработало
matched_records = re.findall(record_pattern, self._file.read()) не сработало    

self._idx - изменить не получиолсь
+ 'word=word.encode('utf8')'

line 189, in __getitem__ : return self._idx[tuple(word)] 
KeyError: (116, 101, 115, 116)  (или b't',b'e',b's',b't')

#### вот пример из 10 элементов self._idx

>>> print (list(self._idx)[:10])
[(b'a', b' ', b'f', b'a', b't', b' ', b'l', b'o', b't', b' ', b'o', b'f', b' ',
b'g', b'o', b'o', b'd'), (b'a', b' ', b'f', b'o', b'r', b't', b'i', b'o',  
b'r', b'i'), (b'a', b' ', b'l', b'a'), (b'a', b' ', b'p', b'i', b'e', b'c', 
b'e', b' ', b'o', b'f', b' ', b'c', b'a', b'k', b'e'), (b'a', b' ', b'p', 
b'o',b's', b't', b'e', b'r', b'i', b'o', b'r', b'i'), (b'a', b' ', b'p',
b'r', b'i', b'o', b'r', b'i'), (b'a', b'-', b'b', b'o', b'm', b'b'), (b'a',
b'.', b'm', b'.'), (b'a', b'b', b'a', b'c', b'k'), (b'a', b'b', b'a', b'c',
b'u', b's')]
```

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы резко уменьшить код, удалив все, что не относится к проблеме? :)

Answer (score 0):

ответ `self._file.read()` либо `self._file не str`

```
matched_records = re.findall(record_pattern, self._file.read())
```